# Select by multiple value in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I hava such table structure.
[image: my table structure]

Now I need to find levels that have more then 90 in "chips" and more then 1000 in "coins". How to make this request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and gives you all rows with more then 90  "chips" and more then 1000 "coins".

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNTIF((key = 'chips' AND value.int_value > 90) 
              OR (key = 'coins' AND value.int_value > 1000)) 
  FROM UNNEST(event_dim.params) 
) > 1
```

Note: above query assumes key uniqueness within each row - which is most likely a case.

Below variation gives you all levels and count of respective rows with more then 90  "chips" and more then 1000 "coins"

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT param.value.int_value, COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM yourTable, UNNEST(event_dim.params) AS param
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNTIF((key = 'chips' AND value.int_value > 90) 
              OR (key = 'coins' AND value.int_value > 1000)) 
  FROM UNNEST(event_dim.params) 
) > 1
AND param.key = 'level'
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: it's working, but I can't understand why are you using OR operator in COUNTIF, if you need to have both conditions be true, and not only one of them?

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM data
WHERE ((SELECT COUNTIF((key = 'chips' AND value.int_value > 90)) FROM UNNEST(event_dim.params)) > 0 AND (SELECT countif((key = 'coins' AND value.int_value > 1000)) FROM UNNEST(event_dim.params)) > 0)
```

Where data is your input row:

```
WITH data AS(
SELECT STRUCT<name string, params ARRAY<struct<key string, value STRUCT<string_value string, int_value int64> >>> ('level_up', [STRUCT('level' as key, STRUCT('null' as string_value, 19 as int_value) as value), STRUCT('firebase_event_origin' as key, struct('app' as string_value, null as int_value) as value), struct('chips' as key, STRUCT('null' as string_value, 97 as int_value) as value), STRUCT('coins' as key, struct('null' as string_value, 4085 as int_value) as value), STRUCT('powerups' as key, STRUCT('null' as string_value, 19 as int_value) as value)]) event_dim
)
```

Notice that this is using the [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) version of BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is for modified version of Firebase BigQuery analytics:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `myBigQueryProjectName.analytics_61118416.events_20180727`
WHERE 
event_name in ("notification_receive", "event_notification_received")
AND
(SELECT COUNTIF((key = "machine_name" AND value.string_value in("promo_name")) --begin of filtering request
              OR (key = "type" AND value.string_value in ("background"))
              ) 
              FROM UNNEST(event_params) 
) > 1  -- end of filtering request (Number must be less or equal of amount of if statements in countif!!!
AND platform = "ANDROID"
```